# Connecting a Wii remote to the Pi

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to connect a Wii remote to the Pi and use it in a python script. I've tried XWiiMote, but I can't get it to compile. All of the other libraries for Wiimotes I've found don't even work anymore (Wiican, CWiid). Has anyone had any luck with this? XWiiMote has python bindings, it's perfect.

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried to compile XWiiMote?

Comment: [using ./configure](http://pastebin.com/uYyy8171)

However, I restarted the pi and tried ./autogen.sh again and it may have worked. It's compiling now.

Comment: It looks like xwiimote installed fine, but the bindings won't install now. [link to error](http://pastebin.com/rvW5PU0D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by installing cwiid:

```
sudo apt-get install python-cwiid
```

Next set your bluetooth adapter to discoverable mode:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

next open a python console by entering **python** at the command line.

import the cwiid module:

```
import cwiid
```

press **1 and 2** on you wiimote to make it discoverable

then create a reference to the wiimote and save it for later access:

```
wm = cwiid.Wiimote()
```

Further details and info on making the connection more reliable are available [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/wiimote/).